# How to assign three finger tap into right click menu on Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11, touchpad

I'm using two laptops for a reason. My older Win10 laptop can't assign 2-finger *tap* at all, only scrolling etc. to 2-finger *swipe*, so I am used to assign right click menu to 3-finger tap for years.

[image: pic]

Then I have to use a newer Win11 laptop which uses 2-finger tap, it could assign other use or custom shortcut to 3-finger tap but not right click menu.

[image: pic]

It confuses me every time I have to switch. I'm thinking is there a way to make Win11 assign right click menu to 3-finger tap? Like is there a shortcut keys for it to assign to 3-finger tap as custom shortcut? I tried Shift+F10 but it is not the same, like it can only use general menu but not when I pointing to a link for example, cmiiw. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You wish to map 3-fingers tap to a right-click?

Comment: Most right click context was removed in Windows 11, and what is there is not much (if any) customizable

Comment: @harrymc yes that's pretty much it

Comment: @John ugh why win10 can but not win11 microsoft

Comment: Because Windows 11 removed right context and no sign it is coming back. Windows 11 is NOT Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a touch screen to test on, but according to the documentation
the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/)
can help.

The following example script is supposed to map
3-fingers tap to a right-click:

```
+^#F22:: MouseClick, right
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)